# Is it possible to get a depth first object ordering from git rev-list?

Tags: git, git-rev-list, git-plumbing

I can almost get a depth first ordering with `git rev-list --in-commit-order --objects --reverse HEAD` which gives me something like

```
commit A
tree AA
blob A
blob B
commit B
tree BA
...
```

When I want

```
blob B
blob A
tree AA
commit A
...
```

Post processing the list to depth first isn't straight forward because two trees of common ancestry might share the same child like

```
tree A is parent of tree B and blob A
tree B is parent of blob A
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible.

Comment: With `git rev-list` alone, I doubt it, with an extra script to read and reorder the output, possibly. Could you describe the usage you intend to have of the output ?

Comment: @LeGEC I'm encrypting the object graph so I need to traverse the merkle tree depth first to rebuild it.

Comment: The problem with reordering the input which I currently do is that if tree A and a descendant tree B share blob A, blob A is listed more adjacent to tree A. I might have to just walk the graph myself.